# How can I use a string and integer in same code?

Tags: python-3.x

so I have started to write a code which will only allow the user to enter numbers specifically 7 or 8 numbers only.e.g 12345678
code that only allows number:

```
NumGiven=''

while not NumGiven.isnumeric():

NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:')
```

but when I try to use:

```
while NumGiven<7 and NumGiven>8:
    NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:')
```

It gives me an error : unorderable types: str() and int().
So my question is how can I only allow the user to enter numbers and is only allowed to enter 7 or 8 digits , no more and no less.

I did some research and I found that I had to use 
`NumGiven=int(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))`
but then it would give me : 'int'object has no attribute 'isnumeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len(NumGiven)` returns the length of a string.

`while len(NumGiven)<7 and len(NumGiven)>8:` is incorrect as well.  How can a number be both <7 and >8?  Here's a solution that will wait for the correct input:

```
while True:
    NumGiven = input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:')
    if NumGiven.isnumeric() and len(NumGiven) in (7,8):
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter a 7- or 8-digit number.')
# Now the input is valid, convert to integer if needed
num = int(NumGiven)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `len()` method to get the length of the string.

```
while len(NumGiven)<7 or len(NumGiven)>8:
```

In your code you're checking whether the value of `NumGiven` is less than 7 *and* (should be *or*) greater than 8. Since the value of `NumGiven` is in fact a string, it doesn't make sense to try to compare it to numbers.

Re: your edit: no, don't use

```
NumGiven=int(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
```

Leave it as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your help too, I just need to change 'and' to 'or'

Comment: @123abc You're right, you need to change `and` to `or`, but you also need to use `len()`. Both are essential points here.

Answer (score -2):

input function reads a string, so you might need to convert if to int and then perform checks. Also you need to check for length of string read:

```
NumGiven=input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:')
while len(NumGiven)==7 or len(NumGiven)==8:
   NumGiven=input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:')
else:
   raise TypeError
```